# Expected argument type error, Doctrine, API Platform

Tags: api, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

Appologies for the poorly worded question, I have no idea what the error is or why I have it, so I am posting it here in the hopes that someone can help me to understand what it is reporting and how I would fix it.

[image: error being reported]

On my `messages` entity I have the following:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Groups", inversedBy="messages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"messages:read", "messages:write"})
     */
    private $groups;
```

and in `groups`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Message", mappedBy="groups", orphanRemoval=true)
 * @GroupAnnotation({"groups:read"})
 */
private $messages;
```

I imagine I have left out some information so please let me know what other data is required and I'll update the ticket.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you have a `use App\Entity\Groups;` clause somewhere in your file header and also you use `@Groups` which will assume you mean the Entity - which you probably don't. So ... I believe you actually meant `@GroupAnnotation` just as in your second code sample? you probably have the correct `use` clause for GroupAnnotation there perhaps as well?

Comment: omg, such an easy fix - thanks so much